# JavaScript Object grouping and filtering

Tags: javascript

How to separate all fields whose key ends with 0x into a separate object/array using filter.

That is, all 00s, 01s, 02s must be filters out into a separate object or array.

The use the object entries to separate it by index but it fails when field is missing. So the day here is dynamic i.e sometime some fields are not entered. I guess filtering is the only way?

```
 {
     "hotel00": "asdasd",
      "adult00": "asdasd",
      "child00": "asdasd",
      "infant00": "asdasd",
      "hotel01": "asdasd",
      "adult01": "asdasd",
      "child01": "asdasd",
      "infant01": "asdas",
      "hotel02": "asdasdas",
      "adult02": "asdasd",
      "child02": "asdasd",
      "infant02": "asdasd",
      "hotel10": "asdasd",
      "adult10": "asdasd",
      "child10": "asdsd",
      "infant10": "asd",
      "hotel11": "asdsd",
      "adult11": "asd",
      "child11": "asdsd",
      "infant11": "asd",
      "hotel12": "asdasd",
      "adult12": "asdasd",
      "child12": "asdasdasd",
      "infant12": "asdsdasd",
    }
```

Output

```
       {
  "a": [
    {
      "hotel00": "asdasd",
      "adult00": "asdasd",
      "child00": "asdasd",
      "infant00": "asdasd",
    },
    {
      "hotel01": "asdasd",
      "adult01": "asdasd",
      "child01": "asdasd",
      "infant01": "asdas",
    },
    {
      "hotel02": "asdasdas",
      "adult02": "asdasd",
      "child02": "asdasd",
      "infant02": "asdasd",
    }
  ],
    "b": [
      {
        "hotel10": "asdasd",
        "adult10": "asdasd",
        "child10": "asdsd",
        "infant10": "asd",
      },
      {
        "hotel11": "asdsd",
        "adult11": "asd",
        "child11": "asdsd",
        "infant11": "asd",
      },
      {
        "hotel12": "asdasd",
        "adult12": "asdasd",
        "child12": "asdasdasd",
        "infant12": "asdsdasd",
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What entries start with 0? I don't see anything that starts with 0 in your object

Comment: hotel00, adult00 infant00 it has to be part of the same group...

Comment: Do you have any `001` for example . So 3 digits or more ? And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You can use linqJs for grouping and filtering.It has lots of facilities

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this does delivers the answer to your question

```js
const obj =  {
  "hotel00": "asdasd",
   "adult00": "asdasd",
   "child00": "asdasd",
   "infant00": "asdasd",
   "hotel01": "asdasd",
   "adult01": "asdasd",
   "child01": "asdasd",
   "infant01": "asdas",
   "hotel02": "asdasdas",
   "adult02": "asdasd",
   "child02": "asdasd",
   "infant02": "asdasd",
   "hotel10": "asdasd",
   "adult10": "asdasd",
   "child10": "asdsd",
   "infant10": "asd",
   "hotel11": "asdsd",
   "adult11": "asd",
   "child11": "asdsd",
   "infant11": "asd",
   "hotel12": "asdasd",
   "adult12": "asdasd",
   "child12": "asdasdasd",
   "infant12": "asdsdasd",
 }
 
const {a,b,c,d,e,f} = Object.keys(obj).reduce(({a,b,c,d,e,f}, val, index) => ({
     a: /00\b(?<=\w)/.test(val)  ? {...a, [val]:obj[val]} : a,
     b: /01\b(?<=\w)/.test(val)  ? {...b, [val]:obj[val]} : b,
     c: /02\b(?<=\w)/.test(val)  ? {...c, [val]:obj[val]} : c,
     d: /10\b(?<=\w)/.test(val)  ? {...d, [val]:obj[val]} : d,
     e: /11\b(?<=\w)/.test(val)  ? {...e, [val]:obj[val]} : e,
     f: /12\b(?<=\w)/.test(val)  ? {...f, [val]:obj[val]} : f,
   }),{a:{},b:{},c:{},d:{},e:{},f:{}})

 const results = {
   a: [a,b,c],
   b: [d,e,f]
 };
 
 console.log(results)
```

> LE second example

```js
const obj =  {
  "hotel00": "asdasd",
   "adult00": "asdasd",
   "child00": "asdasd",
   "infant00": "asdasd",
   "hotel01": "asdasd",
   "adult01": "asdasd",
   "child01": "asdasd",
   "infant01": "asdas",
   "hotel02": "asdasdas",
   "adult02": "asdasd",
   "child02": "asdasd",
   "infant02": "asdasd",
   "hotel10": "asdasd",
   "adult10": "asdasd",
   "child10": "asdsd",
   "infant10": "asd",
   "hotel11": "asdsd",
   "adult11": "asd",
   "child11": "asdsd",
   "infant11": "asd",
   "hotel12": "asdasd",
   "adult12": "asdasd",
   "child12": "asdasdasd",
   "infant12": "asdsdasd",
 }

 const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,val)=>{
    ['00','01','02','10','11','12'].forEach((item, index) => {
      const x = index<3 ? 'a' : 'b';
      const i = index<3 ? index : index-3;
      acc[x][i] = val.substring(val.length-2) === item ? {...acc[x][i], [val]:obj[val]} : acc[x][i];
    })
    return acc;
 },{a:[],b:[]})

 console.log(result)
```

Comment: added a second example hope it's simpler